# Cant find bashrc file

Tags: macos

I need to add a line to my .bashrc file. But I can't find the file. Is it possible that I don't have one?

I have looked in OSdisk/users/myName(the one with the house) 
but its not there. Hidden files and folders are showing.

Is it possible that I don't have one?

Comment: It's entirely possible you don't have one. macOS accounts don't have them unless you (or some software you install/use) create one. You can check with the command `ls ~/.bashrc` -- if it lists the name, you have one, but if it says "No such file or directory", you don't.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Seems like I don't have one. Could I create one my self? Could it cause any harm if its not done right?

Comment: You can certainly create one yourself. Yes, it can mess up your Terminal environment (in some situations) if it's done wrong. But by default, .bashrc isn't run for new Terminal sessions (those run ~/.bash_profile instead), so it won't affect those. On the other hand, if you *wanted* it to affect those, then you may want to create that instead (or you can put something like `[ -f ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc` in your ~/.bash_profile, and then put the actual setup in ~/.bashrc). If something goes wrong, move/rename the relevant file and open a new Terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

The file you want is .bashrc. The first character in the files name is a period. ,bashrc should be in your home directory. Hidden files must be shown. If you still cant find it you can try using the .bash_profile file. While in your home folder you can type `ls .bash*` and it will show you that file if it exists.